# How to convert from Q64.96 represented as bytes to BigFloat in Rust

Tags: rust, floating-point, ethereum, fixed-point

I am trying to convert from a Q64.96 to a BigFloat. The Q64.96 number is initially represented as a U256 type from [the ethers-rs crate](https://docs.rs/ethers/0.17.0/ethers/types/struct.U256.html).

I first convert the value to big endian bytes. Then I am trying to convert to [BigFloat from the num-bigfloat crate](https://docs.rs/num-bigfloat/1.6.0/num_bigfloat/struct.BigFloat.html).

To do this, I am using the [BigFloat::from_bytes associated function](https://docs.rs/num-bigfloat/1.6.0/num_bigfloat/struct.BigFloat.html#method.from_bytes) but I am not sure how to derive the exponent from bytes when the number represented as a Q64.96. Can someone help me figure out how to convert this value to BigFloat?

Comment: Do you know if the Q64.96 is unsigned or signed?

Comment: 0xKitsune, post your relevant code here.

Comment: @PitaJ the Q64.96 is unsigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `from_bytes` is what you want here. Given that what's stored in the `U256` is essentially a 160-bit unsigned integer, I'd construct the `BigFloat` directly from the constituent `u64`s like so:

```rust
fn convert(q64_96: U256) -> BigFloat {
    let least_sig = q64_96.0[0];
    let second_sig = q64_96.0[1];
    let third_sig = q64_96.0[2];
    let most_sig = q64_96.0[3];

    let bf2 = BigFloat::from(2);
    let bf64 = BigFloat::from(64);
    let bf128 = BigFloat::from(128);
    let bf192 = BigFloat::from(192);
    let bf96 = BigFloat::from(96);

    (
        (BigFloat::from(most_sig) * bf2.pow(&bf192)) +
        (BigFloat::from(third_sig) * bf2.pow(&bf128)) +
        (BigFloat::from(second_sig) * bf2.pow(&bf64)) +
        BigFloat::from(least_sig)
    ) / bf2.pow(&bf96)
}
```

However, it may not be perfectly accurate due to how floats work.

I'm curious what your use case for this conversion is. Fixed-point arithmetic is generally more predictable, and the Q64.96 has a ton of precision.